# searchbutton event is not working in cordova 5.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am creating an android app in **cordova 5.0**,  **searchbutton** event is not working in while backbutton and volumedown events are working fine.

my code is bellow

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

    function onBackKeyDown () {
        if($location.path() == '/home'){
             navigator.app.exitApp();
            }else {
                $location.path('/home')
            }

    }


    document.addEventListener("searchbutton", onSearchKeyDown, false);

    function onSearchKeyDown() {
        alert('searchbutton');
    }

    document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", onVolumeDownKeyDown, false);

    function onVolumeDownKeyDown() {
        alert('volumedownbutton');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the above events(searchbutton,backbutton click) inside "deviceready" event and then try. It will work.

Comment: i am register these events with device ready but it is not working